# Construct a line segment perpendicular to a given line segment and through its endpoint

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given the $x$-$y$ coordinates of the start and end points of line segment, draw another segment with a given length $L$ perpendicular to an endpoint of the first segment and determine the coordinate of its constructed endpoint.

[image]

Comment: okay, and, is the endpoint of the perpendicular line segment concurrent with the endpoint of the original line segment?

Comment: you can use the point slope formula

Comment: Find the slope $m_1$ of your given line.  The slope of your constructed line obeys $m_2 = -1/m_1$.  Your new line is $y = m_2 x + b$ where $b$ is found so the line passes through an endpoint.

Comment: Thank you @SakethMalyala and @ David for the tips. This is not so clear to me. I do not want the line passing through the endpoint but rather stopping there).

I will edit my post to include what I want at the end of the day: the xy-coordinate of the endpoint of the line length drawn.

Comment: So, to be clear: You want to draw another segment, starting at an endpoint of the existing segment, so you end up with an L-shaped figure, right?

Comment: @MPW . Yes, spot on!

Comment: When you say construct, what exactly do you mean? For if you need the coordinates of the endpoint, then @David's advice suffices, since you know the length of the segment and one of its endpoints. This equation, together with the equation of the line, should give you the coordinates needed. To actually do this with compass and straightedge, use Thales' theorem -- *an angle inscribed in a semi-circle is a right angle,* thus: Draw a circle passing through one endpoint of the given segment so that it intersects the segment at another point $Q.$ Then draw the line $QO,$ where $O$ is the centre...

Comment: ...of the circle. This intersects the circle at another point $Q'$ diametrically opposite to $Q.$ Then join $Q'$ to the original point of intersection to get a right angle there. Finally, cut off your desired segment of length $L.$

Comment: Thank you, @amd.  I'll check that link out.

Comment: @Allawonder , my post has been modified by Moderators including the addition of the word "construct". I never intended to use such a term. Thank you also for the explanation you've offered there.